# Scraping tables with hiden rows from a webpage

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape this table (https://rk.americaeconomia.com/display/embed/multilatinas/2019). As you can see, the table has two types of rows: "dataRow" and "extraDataRow", and both types of rows refer to the same firm/company.

I've trying the code of below but I'm unable to create the Dictionary with the needed information. Any help is appreciated for doing two things: (1) to scrape the complete table with both types of rows, and (2) to create a dataframe for storing "all" the data related to each firm.

Thanks in advance.

```
def getHTMLContent(link):
html = urlopen(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
return soup

content = getHTMLContent('https://rk.americaeconomia.com/display/embed/multilatinas/2019')
tables = content.find_all('table')
table = content.find('table', {'class': 'table'})
for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
if(tr.get('class')==['dataRow']):
    print(cell.text)
elif ((tr.get('class') == ['extraDataRow'])):
    print(cell.text)
```

My output should look like this

```
Firm   Country    Sector   %Multi  Ranking18   Total sales 2018  ...



Cols 1-4 are in "dataRow". Cols 5, 6 .......  are in "extraDataRow".
```

In "extraDataRow" I've 32 columns with extra information of each firm, and I want the information of all these 32 columns joined to the information of the first four columns ("dataRow"). I want all the information in table format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick solution I came up with.

I created a function to get all the headers from the first extraDetails row found, and the first normal row found. Then I get all the normal rows. I loop through all the rows and use the data-target attribute to get the extra details row. Using this data I create an object, using the headers as a reference that formats the data in the way requested.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_headers(soup):
    header_names = []
    headers = soup.find('thead').find_all('th')

    for h in headers:
        header_names.append(h.text)

    extra_headers = soup.find(attrs={
            'class': 'extraDataRow'
        }).find_all(attrs={
            'class': 'extraMiniHeader'
        })

    for h in extra_headers:
        header_names.append(h.text)

    return header_names

html = urlopen('https://rk.americaeconomia.com/display/embed/multilatinas/2019')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

headers = get_headers(soup)
rows = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'dataRow'})
results = []
for r in rows:
    result = {}
    data = r.find_all('td')
    data_count = len(data)
    for i in range(0, data_count):
        result[headers[i]] = data[i].text
    extra = soup.find(attrs={
        'data-link': r.attrs.get('data-target'), 
        'class': 'extraDataRow'
    })
    extra_data = extra.find_all(attrs={
            'class': 'extraMiniValue'
        })

    extra_count = len(extra_data)

    for i in range(data_count, data_count + extra_count):
        result[headers[i]] = extra_data[i - data_count].text

    results.append(result)

# Prints First Result
print(results[0])
```

Comment: Thank you @Johnathan Irvin for your answer. Your code worked very well. It was just what I needed.

Comment: @mlosada Awesome! Please make sure you mark me as the correct answer. Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't need to bother with all that - just use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
table = pd.read_html('your url')
tables[0]
```

The output is your target table.

Comment: Thanks Jack Fleeting for your answer. I applied your solution and I got a table with two types of rows. 1 (for dataRow, which is OK) and (2) a line with all the hiden information in "extraDataRow". I Apologize if I was not clear in my request, but I want the information of extraDataRow in a like-Table format (with rows and cols) that I can join to the information of dataRow cell as the information is about the same company.

Comment: @mlosada  Not sure I understand what you mean by that. You may want to edit your question to provide a sample of your exact desired output.

Comment: @mlosada I think the table generated with the method in the answer is what you are looking for: it has  37 columns (the 5 from the dataRow and the 32 from extraDataRow) and 206 rows. If not, I'm still now sure what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you @Jack Fleeting for our answer. The suggestion of Johnathan Irvin worked very well: I got 36 columns and 100 rows!